# Node js, TCP request from front-end causing crash

Tags: angularjs, node.js, sockets, tcp

I am creating a website that involves the user pressing a button which performs a http request to my node server. From there, my node server opens a TCP socket using "net.Socket()". Afterwards, I send a response after the message was successfully delivered using res.send("ok"). When a user presses it multiple times I get the error below. Also, when the server I am communication to with the TCP is not available, the same issue occurs as well. Is there a way I can prevent multiple requests from a user or when the TCP server is not available from crashing my node server?

```
Can't set headers after they are sent.
        at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:344:11)
        at ServerResponse.header (/Users/kevin/Documents/mic/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:719:10)
        at ServerResponse.send (/Users/kevin/Documents/mic/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:164:12)
        at ServerResponse.json (/Users/kevin/Documents/mic/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:250:15)
        at ServerResponse.send (/Users/kevin/Documents/mic/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:152:21)
        at /Users/*****/Documents/***/routes/***.js:275:15
        at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/*****/Documents/***/routes/***.js:829:5)
        at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
        at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
        at TCP._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:492:12)
```

My function

```
  tcp_client_send('***.***.*.***', 3000, server, function(err, data){
    if(err){
      logger.log('error', err);
      return next("err_msg");
    }
    else{
      logger.log('info', 'Successfully sent message.');
      res.send("ok);
    }
  });

//TCP Client send
function tcp_client_send(ip, port, data, cb) {
  var client = new net.Socket();
  var message;

  client.connect(port, ip, function() {
    client.write(JSON.stringify(data));
    client.destroy();
  });

  client.on('data', function(data){
    message = data.toString();
  });

  client.on('close', function(){
    cb(null, message);
  });

  client.on('error', function(err) {
    client.destroy();
    cb(err, null);
  });
}
```

Comment: Problem maybe here: `client.write(JSON.stringify(data)); client.destroy();` because `write` is async. Try destroy client inside write-callback function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will call the callback twice if an error occurs:

```
client.on('close', function(){
  cb(null, message); // <-- here
});

client.on('error', function(err) {
  client.destroy();
  cb(err, null);     // <-- and here
});
```

The [fine manual](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_event_error) states, about the `error` event:

> Emitted when an error occurs. The `'close'` event will be called directly following this event.

So both the `close` and `error` handlers are called, and both call the callback.

You should check the argument passed to the `close` handler, which will be `true` when an error had occurred. In that case, don't call the callback:

```
client.on('close', function(hadError) {
  if (! hadError) cb(null, message);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!